# Concatenate several different shape matrices into one, padding zeroes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
b = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
c = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]
```

How can I concatenate a, b and c into one matrix?
If the shapes don't match, like above, pad zeroes to make it match.

In this case:

```
a.shape => (1, 4)
b.shape => (2, 4)
c.shape => (1, 3, 3)
```

The output shape I would like should be: `(2, 4, 3)` because it's the largest dimension.

Comment: You have to choose the desired result shape and layout.  I see a (1,4), (2,4) and (1,3,3).  There isn't an obvious common shape.  `concatenate` has some well documented requires for matching dimensions.

Comment: I would like to concatenate using the largest dimension. That is, (2, 4, 3). Is that possible with bare concatenate? @hpaulj

Comment: Create a `zeros` array of that size, and copy the arrays to the desired slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [125]: a = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
     ...: b = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
     ...: c = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]
```

Your desired result array:

```
In [126]: res = np.zeros((2,4,3), int)
```

Now lets assign values:

To assign the (1,4) `a` to the array we have to use:

```
In [128]: res[[0],:,0] = a
```

and `b`:

```
In [129]: res[:,:,0] = b
```

however I think this overwrites some or all of `a`

and `c`:

```
In [131]: res[[1],:3,:] = c
```

the result:

```
In [132]: res
Out[132]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 0],
        [3, 0, 0],
        [4, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [4, 0, 0]]])
```

I can see the `c` block in the 2nd plane.  In the first plane I see `a`, or is it the first 'row' of `b`.  In the second plane I see part of `b`, but the rest has been overwritten by `c`.

Here's a better way of fitting the blocks:

```
In [141]: res = np.zeros((2,4,3), int)
In [142]: res[[1],:3,:] = c
In [143]: res[[0],:,0] = np.array(a)*10
In [144]: res[0,:,1:] = np.array(b).T*100
In [145]: res
Out[145]: 
array([[[ 10, 100, 100],
        [ 20, 200, 200],
        [ 30, 300, 300],
        [ 40, 400, 400]],

       [[  1,   2,   3],
        [  4,   5,   6],
        [  7,   8,   9],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

But normally when we concatenate arrays, we put a new array on its 'own' dimension,

For example start with 3 planes, one for each of the 3 inputs:

```
In [146]: res = np.zeros((3,3,4), int)
In [147]: res[0,0,:] = np.array(a)*10
In [148]: res[1,:2,:] = np.array(b)*100
In [149]: res[[2],:3,:3] = np.array(c)
In [150]: res
Out[150]: 
array([[[ 10,  20,  30,  40],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]],

       [[100, 200, 300, 400],
        [100, 200, 300, 400],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]],

       [[  1,   2,   3,   0],
        [  4,   5,   6,   0],
        [  7,   8,   9,   0]]])
```

As initially commented, there isn't a single, obvious layout that for this mix of shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to extend each vector to the desired shape and then to concatenate them:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
c = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]])

# New dimensions:
len1 = 2
len2 = 4
len3 = 3

# Resize and reshape all vectors to match new dims
# .reshape() pads zeros to array in place 
a.resize(len1*len2*len3)
new_a = a.reshape(len1,len2,len3)
b.resize(len1*len2*len3)
new_b = b.reshape(len1,len2,len3)
c.resize(len1*len2*len3)
new_c = c.reshape(len1,len2,len3)

print(new_a) 
print(new_a.shape) # output: (2, 4, 3)
print(new_a.shape == new_b.shape == new_c.shape == (len1, len2, len3)) # output: True

new_arr = np.concatenate([new_a, new_b, new_c])
print(new_arr)
```